# How can I use the SQL "and" statement in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to make a query something like

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE title='Pulp Fiction' AND year='1994'
```

but using Entity Framework I can't do this

```
var query = from m in db.movies
            where m.title =='Pulp Fiction'
            AND m.year == '1994'//<----- this I can't do
            select m;
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: nit: AND in this context is an *operator*. Operators are used to combine *expressions* to form large *expressions*. Expressions are component parts of *statements*. Statements are a complete "unit". In SQL, say, you have a `SELECT` statement, which is composed of various clauses (`SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, etc). In C#, you have an assignment statement, such as `var a = 5 + i;`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for the illumination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var query = from m in db.movies
            where m.title =='Pulp Fiction'
            && m.year == '1994'
            select m;
```

you're coding C# here so you should use C# and syntax that is &&

Comment: Lol I can't believe I didn't think that. Thanks. :)

Comment: :) Glad to be able to hlep buddy.

Answer (score 3):

You use the C# syntax for the expression, i.e. the `&&` operator:

```
var query =
  from m in db.movies
  where m.title == 'Pulp Fiction' && m.year == '1994'
  select m;
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be `&&` instead of `AND`:

```
var query = from m in db.movies
            where m.title == 'Pulp Fiction'
            && m.year == '1994'
            select m;
```